# Lock Panorama Title/Image

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is there a way to lock the Title of Panorama Control, so that it does not slide as the pages are switched? Instead it remains in its place?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably place the panorama inside of a grid with 2 rows. The first row can contain text, image or whatever you want to remain static. Then place the panorama control inside of the second row. Check this out:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image x:Name="Logo" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <controls:Panorama Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,-60,0,0">
         <controls:Panorama.Title><Rectangle Height="60"/></controls:Panorama.Title>
    ...
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This seems like it'd ALMOST work, but the background of the Panorama will get pushed down and not under the Logo. It seems like this approach would work without any row definitions, however.. right?

Comment: You could apply a negative TOP MARGIN to the Panorama. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you don't want paralax title layer for panorama.

If so, try this:

```
public class NoParalaxTitleLayer : PanningTitleLayer
    {
        protected override double PanRate
        {
            get { return 0d; }
        }
    }

    public class NoParalaxBackgroundLayer : PanningBackgroundLayer
    {
        protected override double PanRate
        {
            get { return 1d; }
        }
    }
```

And with style:

```
<Style x:Key="NonParalaxPanorama" TargetType="controls:Panorama">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Panorama">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <local:NoParalaxBackgroundLayer x:Name="BackgroundLayer" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                <Border x:Name="background" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
                            </local:NoParalaxBackgroundLayer>
                            <local:NoParalaxTitleLayer x:Name="TitleLayer" 
                 CacheMode="BitmapCache" 
                 ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" 
                 Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" 
                 FontSize="187" 
                 FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Margin="10,-76,0,9" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <controlsPrimitives:PanningLayer x:Name="ItemsLayer" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1">
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="items"/>
                            </controlsPrimitives:PanningLayer>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

<controls:Panorama Style="{StaticResource NonParalaxPanorama}">
</controls:Panorama>
```